# RGB and conditional instruction in .kv file

Tags: kivy

So I've been working on an application, and tried to use a conditional kv instruction in kv, as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/1F4R1uBnR0M).

```
<myWidget@Widget>:
    size: self.parent.width-self.height*0.5, self.parent.height/12
    selected: False
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgb: 1,1,0 if self.selected else 1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.parent.width-self.height*0.5, self.parent.height/12
```

My problem is that I don't understand the rgb behaviour : while the colours in this example work fine (turns to yellow when selected and back to white when unselected), other colour combinations will give unpredictable colors, or no result at all.

Could someone explain to me what actually happens to the rgb property ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is being parsed as `(1, 1, (0 if self.selected else 1), 1, 1)`, which obviously isn't what you want but (as you note) happens to work in the case of yellow/white. Try instead

```
rgb: (1,1,0) if self.selected else (1,1,1)
```